# How to read a SOAP xml file using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I was trying to read an xml file and loads it in an xml document. However an error prompted me that the "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." I need to retrieve the message from the xml file.

Below is my code:

```
Dim xmlPath as String = Server.MapPath("~/res.xml")
Dim xmlDoc as New XmlDocument
Dim fs As New FileStream(xmlPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

xmlDoc.Load(fs)
```

Here is the content of the xml file:

```
--uuid:8asdsddf-sdf24-asdasd-3121-asdasdasdasd
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@apache.org>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-
ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-
ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><Status xmlns=""><Message>Success: 12345</Message></Status></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-
ENV:Envelope>
--uuid:8asdsddf-sdf24-asdasd-3121-asdasdasdasd--
```

What should be the reason why the error prompted?

Comment: show us the XML File content

Comment: @shawkyz1 I already posted the xml file content. Thank you!

Comment: That is not XML. The first five lines and the last line are invalid.

Comment: so obviously you can't parse it to XML with the HTTP Headers. Remove them and only parse the body

Comment: also as @Jacob suggested

Comment: @shawkyz1 I'll try. Thank you!

Comment: @shawkyz1 I removed the first five lines and the last, and an error prompted "The URI prefix is not recognized".

Answer (score 0):

The following code should remove all the non xml string from file

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        'Dim xmlPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/res.xml")
        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(FILENAME)

        Dim xml As String = ""
        Dim inputLine As String = ""
        Dim foundTag = False
        While (Not reader.EndOfStream)
            inputLine = reader.ReadLine
            If foundTag = False Then
                If Not inputLine.StartsWith("<") Then Continue While
                foundTag = True
            End If

            If Not inputLine.StartsWith("--") Then
                xml = xml & inputLine
            End If
        End While

        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml)
    End Sub

End Module
```